# Liquid Vacuum Filler machine using Venturi Pump

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, vacuum

We are currently using a liquid vacuum filler machine that vacuum fills nail polish. There is a Gast 1/4 horsepower motor and a Gast rotary vane pump that according to the gast website pulls 20" of vacuum at a flow volume of 4CFM.

I wanted to know if it is possible to switch to a Venturi vacuum pump to accomplish the same thing.

There are four filling heads on the machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

Check out this manufacturers table for reference: [Air Venturi Vacuum Generator Pump for Workholding, Fixturing and Clamping](http://www.2linc.com/venturi_vacuum.htm)

Using the 1/4 npt sized part you can achieve 22-26"Hg at 4.5 scfm vacuum flow which requires 70-80psi compressed air input at 5scfm.

Obviously, your liquid would need to be delivered before flowing into the venturi.

The trade off is compressed air supply for an electric motor. That's probably more of a financial/business/equipment decision that's out of this question's current scope.